# 'BitmapStub' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Graphics' Using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, bitmap, xamarin.android, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I implemented a application for Sunmi T1 mini device in-build printer in Xamarin forms and i want to print a image with some text like billing receipt.

I integrated AIDL file for Sunmi T1 mini device you can see in image.

[image]

But i am facing namespacing issue in IWoyouService.cs "**the type of namespace name 'BitmapStub' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Graphics'.**"

[image]

```
case TransactionPrintBitmap: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                Android.Graphics.Bitmap arg0 = default (Android.Graphics.Bitmap);
                arg0 = Android.Graphics.BitmapStub.AsInterface (data.ReadStrongBinder ());
                ICallback arg1 = default (ICallback);
                arg1 = ICallbackStub.AsInterface (data.ReadStrongBinder ());
                this.PrintBitmap (arg0, arg1);
                reply.WriteNoException ();
                return true;
                }
```

I attach my AIDL Zip file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lrCgZwDrfyqs6LAwTP3pQ6nMzYIW4hrY/view?usp=sharing.

How can resolve this error in Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Check  https://www.greydogconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/5/28/using-aidl-files-in-xamarin .

Comment: hello@LucasZhang-MSFT i sued already this thing

`private ICallback callback = null;
private Intent intent = new Intent();
private WoyouServiceConnection connService = new WoyouServiceConnection();
public string PrintWithImage(byte[] data)
{
 var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
 intent.SetPackage("woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5");
 intent.SetAction("woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService");
 context.StartService(intent);
 context.BindService(intent, connService, 0);
 callback = default(ICallback);
 connService.Service.PrinterInit(callback);
 return "";
}`

Comment: Jar binding will not work with Android Library Projects, you need to include .aar file. Jar files do not reference android specific libraries in jar, but .aar file correctly references all required android related libraries.

Comment: How can integrate .aar file in xamarin

Comment: and where i using .jar file those not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem, and managed to solve it by adding another AIDL file to define what a 'Bitmap' is.

I copied [this file](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.aidl) from the Android Open Source Project and just added it into my project and set the build action to Android Interface Definition like the other Sunmi AIDL files.

Not sure why Xamarin doesn't manage to handle this automatically, but adding this solved the problem for me and I was able to build and successfully invoke the interface methods that accept bitmap parameters.

In case the link ever goes bad, here is the entire file you need to add - it's very small:

```
/* Save this in Bitmap.aidl and add to your project alongside the others */

package android.graphics;

parcelable Bitmap;
```